# How to get rid of spaces when printing text and variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, space

I want to make it so the user enters his name/age and it outputs the name and age in ten years. I have set it out like this:

```
    print("Let's find out how old you will be in 10 Years.\n")
    name = input("name: ")

    print("\nNow enter your age,",name,"\n")
    age = int(input("age: "))

    ageinten = age + 10

    print("\n",name,"you will be",ageinten,"in ten years.")

    input("Press Enter to close")
```

The output is like this:

```
    Let's find out how old you will be in 10 Years.

    name: Example

    Now enter your age, Example 

    age: 20

     Example you will be 30 in ten years.
    Press Enter to close
```

But I want it without the space before example:

```
    Example you will be 30 in ten years.
    Press Enter to close
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Better use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
print('\n{} you will be {} in ten years.'.format(name, ageinten))
```

or use `sep=''`, but then you'd have to add trailing and leading spaces to the strings.:

```
print("\n", name, " you will be ", ageinten, " in ten years.", sep='')
```

Default value of `sep` is a space, that's why you're getting a space.

**Demo:**

```
>>> name = 'Example'
>>> ageinten =  '20'
>>> print("\n",name," you will be ",ageinten," in ten years.", sep='')

Example you will be 20 in ten years.
>>> print('\n{} you will be {} in ten years.'.format(name, ageinten))

Example you will be 20 in ten years.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just `print()` to give out newlines.  This seems to fit your current style most:

```
print("Let's find out how old you will be in 10 Years.\n")
name = input("name: ")

print()
print("Now enter your age,",name)
print()
age = int(input("age: "))

ageinten = age + 10

print()
print(name,"you will be",ageinten,"in ten years.")

input("Press Enter to close")
```